# Send intent to open data URI (RFC 2397)?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, rfc, data-uri

I'm trying to send `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,test` but receive following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data:text/html;charset=utf-8,test }
```

Is there any workaround/hack to send intent with data URI, which will be received and processed by browser (desirable by one that supports opening of data URI)?