Image Stored as Data In NFC tag does not open in browser
I wanted for the challenge/fun to store an image directly on an NFC tag (and not on a website - yes i know this is not efficient-)
I saw in this thread  it could be possible using base 64.
Through a python script, I am able to compress an image and encode it into base64, the output of this message is
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAA...

Copied into my phone and PC Firefox browser, this render the image and i am able to see it.
However when i scan the NFC on my android phone this lead to a page where i can neither copy the data, neither do it open in a browser, is there a way to setup the NFC in the NFC tool app such that it opens automatically in a browser?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/U7W3f9L5j8mMvZnw8
in this drive pictures of the configurations I tried in NFC tool, and what it does when it is in "text mode"
Do you know a way to have the data copied to the clipboard or to open it directly in a browser? Best would be a way to tell the phone that it is an "openable" link

I'd guess the problem is that your phone doesn't know how to handle data of this specific format. Since data URLs have a different scheme than "normal"/website URLs, Android might not know that your data URL is in fact something a browser can handle. I'm not really sure how to work around this, though. See this question for further details, the underlying problem there is the same as in your case.

Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179441/send-intent-to-open-data-uri-rfc-2397
